# Can't install Builded APK android

Tags: java, android, debugging, apk, adb

My app get installed fine when installed through USB "run app" button in Android Studio.

But, when I build a signed APK and install it on my device after unninstalling the old one, it doesn't works:
"Application not installed".

Logcat: (Truncated)

```
2021-05-31 10:59:15.780 8983-30232/? I/Finsky: [63714] adnt.c(3): Verify: Verification package=com.philippemaquin.morinant, id=206 response=0
2021-05-31 10:59:15.840 8983-30224/? I/Finsky: [63710] VerifyPerSourceInstallationConsentInstallTask.mI(2): PSIC verification started with installer uid: 10028 package name: com.google.android.packageinstaller, originating uid: 1001
2021-05-31 10:59:15.884 8983-30224/? I/Finsky: [63710] VerifyPerSourceInstallationConsentInstallTask.mI(10): Skipping logging for attempted installation. The source is a system package.
2021-05-31 10:59:15.885 8983-8983/? I/Finsky: [1] VerifyInstallTask.j(3): Verifying id=206, result=1
2021-05-31 10:59:15.896 1337-1475/? W/PackageManager: installPackageLI
2021-05-31 10:59:15.926 1337-1475/? I/HwPackageManagerServiceEx: addGrantedInstalledPkg package is null
2021-05-31 10:59:15.927 785-21184/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl447352835.tmp: No such file or directory
2021-05-31 10:59:15.931 1337-1450/? I/ActivityManager: App 10028/com.google.android.packageinstaller targets O+, restricted
2021-05-31 10:59:15.944 1337-4645/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {flg=0x2000000 hwFlg=0x10 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFailed (has extras)} from uid 10028
2021-05-31 10:59:15.945 1337-4645/? I/ActivityTaskManager: ActivityRecord info: ActivityInfo{6ecdbde com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFailed}
2021-05-31 10:59:15.945 1337-4645/? I/HwActivityTaskManagerServiceEx: packageName:com.google.android.packageinstaller,requestCode:0,isIntercepted:false,userId:0
...
...
...
2021-05-31 11:00:15.793 8983-8983/? E/Finsky: [1] adzy.run(3): Error while cleaning up task
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.TimeoutFuture$TimeoutFutureException: Timed out: bwt@62c2d68[status=PENDING, info=[tag=[class admo]]]
        at angn.s(PG:3)
        at angn.get(PG:2)
        at anju.c(PG:1)
        at amyd.A(Unknown Source:9)
        at adzy.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.TimeoutFuture$TimeoutFutureException: Timed out: bwt@62c2d68[status=PENDING, info=[tag=[class admo]]]
2021-05-31 11:00:15.793 8983-8983/? I/Finsky: [1] VerifyInstallTask.mH(6): Verification complete: id=206, package_name=com.philippemaquin.morinant
```

I have no clue on how to solve this issue. Any help would be welcome.  :)

Have a nice day

Comment: Did you give the necessary permissions from the developer settings on your phone ?
You must allow to run apk on the phone

Comment: Yes I did. I also tried to install it through google play closed beta but the issue is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by modifying my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-S'
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 30
```

I can't really explain why. Anyway I hope it will help somebody.